# SQL Drop and Create does not script indexes on recreate?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am adding new columns to a table and it is forcing me to drop create the table. Do I have to manually re-add the indexes? Or can I get the generated script to recreate the indexes for me?

Comment: Add the new column at the end and don't drop/recreate the table

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the table designer in Management Studio, then it should recreate any indices/foreign keys automatically.

The only thing I've seen drop from this kind of operation is a schemabound view.  The schema binding (and any associated clustered/full text index) will drop from a schemabound view if you drop/recreate the source table.

Comment: Are the columns that are part of an index being dropped? Or just indexes on the table that has columns being recreated?

Comment: My column is unchanged. The index in question has nothing to do with the columns i am creating.